# What can I do with city,country timezone?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timezone, weather-api

I wanna get current time from specific city, country. API is giving me timezone of city/country, for ex: London

> timezone: 3600

Can I get anything from this info? or do I have to use **lon,lat** to get current time of specific place...

Comment: This is just seconds offset from UTC

Comment: Can I convert it back to UTC offset?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you add 3600 seconds to a UTC time you'll have the time in London (in the summer).

Comment: Actually IDK, I just saw someones code which where using offset to convert current time of spec city, but I realize I had name of city, so I use package 'city-timezones' to get timezone of city, after that 
>        let cityCT = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
              timeZone: `${place.timezone}`,
            });

Comment: Yes, that is a far better option.